# Apache Spark - MLlib - K-Means Input format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I want to perform a K-Means task and fail training the model and get kicked out of Sparks scala shell before I get my result metrics. I am not sure if the input format is the problem or something else. I use Spark 1.0.0 and my input textile (400MB) looks like this:

```
ID,Category,PruductSize,PurchaseAMount
86252,3711,15.4,4.18
86252,3504,28,1.25
86252,3703,10.75,8.85
86252,3703,10.5,5.55
86252,2201,64,2.79
12262064,7203,32,8.49
etc.
```

I am not sure if I can use the first two, because in the MLlib example file there only use floats. So I also tried the last two:

```
16 2.49
64 3.29
56 1
etc.
```

My error code in both cases is here:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans

scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

scala> 

scala> // Load and parse the data

scala> val data = sc.textFile("data/outkmeanssm.txt")
14/08/07 16:15:37 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(35456) called with curMem=0, maxMem=318111744
14/08/07 16:15:37 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values to memory (estimated size 34.6 KB, free 303.3 MB)
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MappedRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:14

scala> val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
parsedData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = MappedRDD[2] at map at <console>:16

scala> 

scala> // Cluster the data into two classes using KMeans

scala> val numClusters = 2
numClusters: Int = 2

scala> val numIterations = 20
numIterations: Int = 20

scala> val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)
14/08/07 16:15:38 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/08/07 16:15:38 WARN LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/08/07 16:15:38 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/08/07 16:15:38 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: takeSample at KMeans.scala:260
14/08/07 16:15:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (takeSample at KMeans.scala:260) with 7 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
14/08/07 16:15:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(takeSample at KMeans.scala:260)
14/08/07 16:15:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
14/08/07 16:15:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
14/08/07 16:15:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (MappedRDD[6] at map at KMeans.scala:123), which has no missing parents
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 7 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MappedRDD[6] at map at KMeans.scala:123)
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 7 tasks
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:0 as TID 0 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:0 as 2221 bytes in 3 ms
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:1 as TID 1 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:1 as 2221 bytes in 0 ms
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:2 as TID 2 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:2 as 2221 bytes in 0 ms
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:3 as TID 3 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:3 as 2221 bytes in 1 ms
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:4 as TID 4 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:4 as 2221 bytes in 0 ms
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:5 as TID 5 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:5 as 2221 bytes in 0 ms
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:6 as TID 6 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:6 as 2221 bytes in 0 ms
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO Executor: Running task ID 4
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO Executor: Running task ID 1
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO Executor: Running task ID 5
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO Executor: Running task ID 6
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO Executor: Running task ID 0
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO Executor: Running task ID 3
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO Executor: Running task ID 2
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:0+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:100663296+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:201326592+24305610
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:33554432+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:67108864+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:134217728+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:167772160+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_3_0 not found, computing it
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:0+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_3_2 not found, computing it
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:67108864+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_3_1 not found, computing it
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:33554432+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_3_4 not found, computing it
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:134217728+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_3_6 not found, computing it
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:201326592+24305610
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_3_3 not found, computing it
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:100663296+33554432
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_3_5 not found, computing it
14/08/07 16:15:39 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/admin/BD_Tools/spark-1.0.0/data/outkmeanssm.txt:167772160+33554432
14/08/07 16:16:53 ERROR Executor: Exception in task ID 5
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.ensureSize(ResizableArray.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.ensureSize(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:83)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedRDD.compute(ZippedRDD.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
14/08/07 16:16:59 ERROR ExecutorUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-5,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.ensureSize(ResizableArray.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.ensureSize(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:83)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedRDD.compute(ZippedRDD.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
14/08/07 16:17:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 5 (task 0.0:5)
Chairs-MacBook-Pro:spark-1.0.0 admin$ 
Chairs-MacBook-Pro:spark-1.0.0 admin$ // Evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors
-bash: //: is a directory
Chairs-MacBook-Pro:spark-1.0.0 admin$ val WSSSE = clusters.computeCost(parsedData)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Chairs-MacBook-Pro:spark-1.0.0 admin$ println("Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = " + WSSSE)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error you are facing will be triggered when you try to add more data into the heap space area in memory, but the size of this data is larger than the JVM can accommodate in the Java heap space.

This occurs due to the fact the applications deployed on Java Virtual Machine are allowed to use only a limited amount of memory. This limit is specified during application startup. To make things more complex, Java memory is separated into two different regions, one of which is called heap. And you have exhausted the heap.

The first solution should be obvious – when you have ran out of a particular resource, you should increase the availability of such a resource. In our case: when your application does not have enough Java heap space memory to run properly, fixing it is as easy as altering your JVM launch configuration and adding (or increasing if present) the following:

```
-Xmx1024m
```